# App crashes after deleting user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So in my app I just made it so that the user can choose to delete their account, and that works out beautifully. However after the account is deleted the app crashes. I think this is because it is trying to search for a user but it's not there.

Here is my code:

```
let loginController = LoginController()

func deleteAccount() {

    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let databaseUser = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId!)

    user?.delete { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            self.present(self.loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    databaseUser.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)
        } else {



        self.present(self.loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        } //Without doing this the user's account only gets deleted in the Authentication, not the whole database. I think this is the problem here?

    })

}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: And the crash log is?

Comment: What day you mean? It's a SIGABRT on the main thread.

Comment: You should copy the crash log from your console and paste in question. There could be n number of reasons for an app crash. It is difficult to understand that from a small code alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to delete the users database as to do that you would need the `let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` which is only active if the user itself is on your backend, Then you go on to delete the `auth`.

```
func deleteAccount() {

let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
let databaseUser = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)

databaseUser.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in

    if error != nil {

        print(error)

    } else {

       user?.delete { error in

          if let error = error {

            print(error) 

          } else {

            self.present(self.loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
 })
}
```

If this still doesn't work track down the lifecycle of the user using debugging tools....

Answer (score 1):

You are **implicitly unwrapping an optional** in this line with `!`:

```
let databaseUser = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId!)
```

You should check whether it's `nil` in the first place with a `guard` statement:

```
guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
    return
}

let databaseUser = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)

[...]
```

Moreover, your code logic is likely to be wrong, as you are getting `nil` for the `userId` before you can work with it.

Comment: What do you suggest that I do? I am trying to delete their whole account meaning it is not dicoverable in the Database or Authentication, so it's like they never signed up.

Comment: I just want to completely delete their account. No references to it left behind.

Comment: Without seeing your whole code structure, it's hard to say. I would suggest tracking the life cycle of a user and check when they disappear from the system.

Comment: What else do you need to see?

Answer (score 0):

The code order is not ideal because deleting the user also logs them out. So the code may be trying to access the users node *after* the user was logged out.

Also remember that Firebase is asynchronous and the only way to know a function has completed is when the code inside the closure executes i.e. in this case the databaseUser.removeValue *may* be firing before the delete user or sometimes it may not.

Code is faster than the internet so it's best to leverage the closures so you know when it's safe to proceed.

Try this sequence; noting that we don't try to delete the Firebase user until we know for sure the data in the users node was deleted. There could use more error checking but you get the idea.

```
let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(uid)
userRef.setValue(nil, withCompletionBlock: { snapshot in
    Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { err in
        if err != nil {
            print(err?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately the app still crashes :( I am most likely implementing this delete function wrong. Would you be able to make the whole function for me just so I can make sure? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jaqueline That is the whole function. Just tested it! Here's how the test was done: I have a user in firebase with uid_x and a /users/uid_x node. I authenticate with that user. I then push a button in the UI that runs the above code. The result is the user/uid_x node is removed, the user is  removed from Firebase and logged out.